# How to store <fo:page-number-citation/> into variable into xsl

Tags: xslt-1.0

I m new to xsl.I m generating PDF from XSL. then i have to attach same ppt at  the end of pdf. so first create pdf using xsl then using java code add ppt files at the end of pdf.

Using   i m getting last page no generated by XSL which is correct(Display N of X in footer of each page) but using java code i m adding 2 pages extra to pdf.

Exmple: Using XSL PDf generate 7 pages and using java it generated 2 pages 
but uisng  in pdf ,the footer of each page shows 1 of 7 till 7 of 7. 
Actually PDf has total 9 pages(7 from xsl and 2 from Java) I want to display 9 as last page in the footer.

```
 <xsl:variable name="java_page">2</<xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="last_page"><fo:page-number-citation ref-id="TheVeryLastPage"/></<xsl:variable>

    <fo:inline><xsl:value-of select="$java_page+$last_page"/></fo:inline>
```

variable java_page store value 2 and variable last_page should store last page  value. but final output shows NaN.
Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 stages to creating a PDF file using XSL.

1. Manipulate data using xsl to generate .fo file (can use variables here)
2. Create PDF from .fo file (cannot use variables here)

It's not possible to save the page # info in a variable for use in stage 2.

To solve your problem try this instead:

1. Add 2 extra pages with the xsl
2. Insert your ppt info into the last 2 pages.
   Do not append the ppt as separate pages, insert them into existing pages.

Comment: thanks jeremy for ur response.but i tried to add ppt file in xsl but i had not found any solution for it.we can add images into xsl. that why we had done this using Java code and append at the end.

Comment: Or add the ppt as an attachment to the PDF instead of separate pages.